# How to retrieve specific columns in a GROUP BY sql statement?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Table `airports`:

```
 id | from | to | price | photo | notes
 _______________________________________
  1 | LON  | JFK|  1000 |       | test
  2 | LON  | JFK|  2000 |       | test2
```

I want to retrieve the bestprice entry of all `from-to` combinations inside the database.
I want to fetch the whole record that is minprice found, or at least specific tables.

The following works, BUT only gives me the 3 columns from, to, price. Not the whole entity.

`SELECT from, to, min(price) FROM airports GROUP BY from, to`

How would I have to adapt this?

Comment: You can use, SUBQUERY / JOIN / APPLY. All these are available in SQL SERVER. But for POSTGRESQL you can search for equivalent of these.

Comment: What do you mean by whole entity?

Comment: The full database row. (lateron mapped to java entity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the results and use distinct on to take the first result from each grouping

```
select distinct on (from,to) * from airports order by from,to,price asc;
```

the above query should work

Comment: How could I ensure that only the `min(price)` row is fetched of each `from,to` couple?

Comment: the order by is supposed to do that, it sorts the prices ascendingly and takes the first

Comment: Which version of postgresql are you using and are you using indices. It seams that performance for this improved a lot from 9.1 to 9.3. While both versions managed to use an index 9.3 was 100 times faster in my test.

Comment: which was your index? `from, to` or `from, to, price`?

Comment: I was using a similar query in my own database to have test data, with an index of (from,to) I can see the difference but using (from,to,price) it dissaperes

Comment: Perfromance wise I process 118954 tuples in 30ms yielding 78 distinct rows

Comment: Can you make an `Explain Analyse` on your db? On mine I get `cost=171123` which is way too much...

Comment: I have 400k entries, and 300k are distinct regarding `from,to`. My query takes 30 sec!

Comment: Unique  (cost=0.42..7810.33 rows=72 width=72) (actual time=0.013..30.690 rows=84 loops=1)
Index Scan using predictions_uid_sid_server_time_index on predictions  (cost=0.42..7214.79 rows=119108 width=72) (actual time=0.011..22.201 rows=119078 loops=1)

Comment: I guess that the difference is that you have 300k distinct values while I have 72, even when the total number of entries are in the same magnitude

Answer (score 4):

This is typically done using window functions:

```
select id, "from", "to", price, photo, notes
from (
    select id, "from", "to", price, photo, notes
           min(price) over (partition by "from", "to") as min_price
    from the_table
) t
where price = min_price
order by id;
```

`from` is a reserved word and it's a bad idea to use that as a column name (not entirely sure about `to`)

To deal with "ties" (same values in from, to and price), you can use the `dense_rank()` function instead:

```
select id, "from", "to", price, photo, notes
from (
    select id, "from", "to", price, photo, notes
           dense_rank() over (partition by "from", "to" order by price) as price_rank
    from the_table
) t
where price_rank = 1
order by id;
```

Comment: regarding `from`: yes you're right, but it's just an example in named of course different on my machine.

Comment: Is it possible to optimize the fetch speed somehow? Eg would certain indexes make sense? If yes, which ones? I tried an index on `{from, to}`, but that did not have any effect...

Comment: @membersound: I would have expected the `distinct on` from lijat's answer to be faster than the window function. I would try an index on `(from, to, price)` but this kind of query is hard to tune.

Comment: Yes, but it at least turned out your query is almost 2x as fast as the distinct.

Comment: I noticed this does sometimes give too much results when there are rows that are equal in `"from", "to", price, photo, notes`. I just would want to pic one of them in these cases.

Comment: @membersound: in that case `dense_rank()` is the better choice. See my edit

Comment: What about dublicate pairs? Would I use `SELECT DISTINCT ON("from", "to", price, photo, notes) * FROM...` here?

Comment: @membersound: `dense_rank()` will take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution would be this. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5f406/5)

```
SELECT * 
FROM airports 
WHERE (from_place, to_place, price) =
(SELECT from_place, to_place, min(price) 
FROM airports 
GROUP BY from_place, to_place);
```

Use `SELECT * FROM ...` since you want the whole entity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the entire data, here is a query that solve your problem:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM airports A
INNER JOIN (SELECT A2.fromhere
                 ,A2.tohere
                 ,MIN(A2.price) AS minprice
            FROM airports A2
            GROUP BY A2.fromhere, A2.tohere) T ON T.fromhere = A.fromhere
                                          AND T.tohere = A.tohere
                                          AND T.minprice = A.price
```

The jointure is used to get only the best prices for each couple fromhere/tohere.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for your remark but have you read my `Remark` at the end of the post??

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I replaced `from` and `to` reserved works by sample column names

Answer (score 0):

There isn't going to be a way to get a "whole entity" there could be many rows in your table that could contain the matching from + to + min price

For example if your table contains

```
id | from | to | price | photo | notes
 _______________________________________
  1 | LON  | JFK|  1000 |       | test
  2 | LON  | JFK|  2000 |       | test2
  3 | LON  | JFK|  5000 |       | test3
  4 | LON  | JFK|  2000 |       | test4
  5 | LON  | JFK|  1000 |       | test5
```

Then both rows 1 and 5 meet your criteria of from + to + min price.

You could write the query

```
SELECT id, from, to, price, photo, notes
FROM airports a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT from, to, min(price) [price]
    FROM airports 
    GROUP BY from, to) sub
    ON sub.from = a.from
   AND sub.to = a.to
   AND sub.price = a.price
```

Which would get you the matching records.

Comment: It would be sufficient in this case to just get one of the found records, doesn't matter which one.

Comment: `[price]` is an invalid identifier in SQL

Comment: I did this based upon MSSQL column alias syntax not sure whether it is OK in standard SQL but it work's in MSSQL